# Fullpage.js: with which function I can restart the ScrollOverflow plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using the fullpage.js add-on "ScrollOverflow" in my project. I use dynamic content on the page, so I need to restart the plugin each time the content changes.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.fn.fullpage.reBuild()` just after you modify the content of the section / slide.

Read more about it [on the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#rebuild).

Comment: Idk how can I miss it in documentation. Many thanks!